# Kivy GMaps, will it work on Kivy Launcher?

Tags: android, google-maps, kivy

I am developing an android application using Kivy. I wanted to try the GMaps sample given in Kivy Launcher but it always crashing. I included the gmaps folder within my app. Will it work on Kivy Launcher?
Also, the buildozer.spec given on the downloaded kivy-gmaps-master should be also included in the directory of my app? Thanks!

Comment: The buildozer.spec won't do anything. I don't know if the gmaps should work, you can [check the error](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) to see what's happening. I wouldn't be surprised if you need to build your own apk though.

Comment: Also, tito did the [mapview](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview) widget which uses openstreetmap, partly to solve problems with the gmaps stuff such as the technical difficulties with implementing it and the fact it only works on android.

Comment: i didn't know about the mapview though +1 for the info :) also, i'm having a hard time building the apk. i've downloaded their virtual builder but once you build it there it always produce error. any clear tutorials or steps about it?

Comment: Post the build log here.

Comment: for the mapview, requirements are futures and requests. i'm using windows 8. can't do the pip install.

Comment: i also forget that i need the current location of the user of the app. is it possible for mapview?

Comment: Presumably you'd use android's location services/gps for that, in which case it's possible with pyjnius and/or plyer.

Comment: yeah i already did it :)) i'm now trying to merge the pyler and the mapview but still thanks for giving time to answer :bd